# Ender 5 Pro starts print then glitches and stops

Tags: creality-ender-5

My Ender 5 Pro starts printing then glitches and stops. It is a brand new printer, and I have printed out the included rabbit model (which came on the MicroSD card), but a couple of days later I turned the printer on and it gave me a blue screen of death.

I have since installed the firmware from Creality's website, but after that, each print results in the printer printing out a bit and stopping (the screen works, but no button can be pressed). I have tried all of the different firmware versions on Creality, but it is the same with all of them (and most printer just doesn't see when I insert the SD card).

The test line (at the very start of the print) on the far right, however, is printed perfectly each time, so the filament goes through without any issue, so it looks like an error in G-code, but the situation (starting and stopping after the test line) is the same both in CURA and Creality slicer.

I have just tried to print using a USB connection and it's working perfectly. So the issue is with the SD card, but I have tried 3 different ones, 2 GB and 16 GB, as well as the included 8 GB one, and the issue is the same on all of them.

What are some reliable cards/manufacturers you used?

Comment: Have you tested the SD cards to see if they work on a computer? It could be the SD card slot on the printer itself.

Comment: @agarza Thanks for the reply. Yeah, all of the microSD cards show up on the PC, and I have loaded a gcode file on all without a problem. And the printer does see the card and even the gcode files, but then just starts prints for like 10 seconds, and then stops printing and responding. I have checked the motherboard and the sd card slot seems intact, and all contacts hotglued.

Comment: While the SD card slot may "look" intact, the internal contacts may have a problem. If the printer is still under warranty, you may try contacting Creality to see if they can remedy the problem.